# Python - Checking if folder exists that has a single quote

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to see if a certain folder exists and then created the directory using Python.  Here is my line:

```
CA00220L001  62.4167 -110.6833  179.0 NT LUTSELK'E A
```

and here is the line that checks if the folder exists:

```
path = r'C:\\data\\world\\'         
with open('C:\\data\\ghcnd-stations.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[38:40] != '  ':
            if not os.path.exists(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[38:40]):
                os.makedirs(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[38:40])
                count = count + 1;
            if not os.path.exists(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[38:40] +'\\' + line[41:71].rstrip()):
                os.makedirs(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[38:40] +'\\' + line[41:71].rstrip())
                count = count + 1;
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[41:72].rstrip()):
                os.makedirs(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[41:72].rstrip())
                count = count + 1
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    os.makedirs(path + country[line[0:2]] + '\\' + line[41:72].rstrip())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "C:\\\\data\\\\world\\\\China \\KING'S PARK"
```

I believe the problem arises from the single quote in LUTSELK'E.  Is there anyway I can get python to recognize that single quote?

Comment: try `"""CA00220L001  62.4167 -110.6833  179.0 NT LUTSELK'E A """` or use `r`

Comment: You can use double quote (") or triple quote (""" or ''') both are valid string in python. If you can give more details then people can give proper answer. What error u are facing? What exact code you tried?

Comment: Use os.path.join within os.path.exists that will escape with '\' and their won't be any problem regarding literal error.

Comment: updated to include the error and more detailed code

Comment: Please use `os.path.join` and put there your parts of your path to be merged or simply instead of  ` \\ ` use `os.sep`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the error more closely I realize the issue was not with the single quote but with the space after China.  I also realized the error is a Windows error and not a Python error.  I was able to change

```
country[line[0:2]]
```

to

```
country[line[0:2]].rstrip()
```

and the script ran fine.